# Как отключить сихронизацию времени между гостевой и хостовой ОС в Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox

Пробовал такую инструкцию:

```
    Если вы пытаетесь сменить время на виртуальной машине и оно все время слетает через несколько секунд, то необходимо: 
Метод 1) В папке с виртуальной машиной отредактировать файл с разрешением *.vbox а имя его зависит от имени ВМ. Нужно добавить строку в ветку Сохранить изменения. 
Метод 2) Выполнить => cmd Выполнить команду cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox" VBoxManage setextradata "VMname" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" "1" Где "VMname" –имя вашей виртуальной машины.
```

Первый метод не помогает.
Второй выдаёт такие ошибки:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage setextradata Win7_x64 "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 0 
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'Win7_x64' 
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown 
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 808 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

ЗЫ По поводу версии virtualbox: в "О программе" указана такая версия - 5.2.14 r123301 (Qt5.6.2)

Comment: Все правильно в команде. Проверьте, может вы пытаетесь сделать это "от имени администратора". Это другой пользователь, у которого в профиле нет этой виртуальной машины

Comment: А может, оно синхронизируется вовсе не с хостовой ОС? Может, гостевая ОС автоматически подключается к NTP-серверам и синхронизирует всё через интернет? Вы проверяли, что NTP отключен?

Comment: @andreymal, проверял. Всё отключено. Сеть тоже отключена.

Answer (score 1):

С командой у вас все правильно

> 9.14.4. Disabling the Guest Additions time synchronization Once installed and started, the VirtualBox Guest Additions will try to
>   synchronize the guest time with the host time. This can be prevented
>   by forbidding the guest service from reading the host clock:
>
> VBoxManage setextradata "VM name"
>   "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1

Выполнять эту команду надо от того же пользователя, под которым вы работаете с этой виртуалкой. Если выполнить её "от имени другого пользователя" или "от имени администратора" то VirtualBox не находит VM в профиле этого пользователя

Comment: Да, это не вызывает ошибки. Сейчас проверю, решило это мою проблему или нет.

Comment: Нет, проблему это не решило. Время всё также синхронизируется (а не должно).